# Transparency no more transparent if opacity is less than 1

Tags: silverlight, png, transparency, opacity

I have a 32-bit PNG representing a blue square in the middle of a transparent square.
Below, I displayed this blue square with 3 different opacity values:

[image: From left to right, opacity is 1, 0.5 and 0.1]

From left to right, opacity is 1, 0.5 and 0.1 and as you can see (if you can't, just trust your Photoshop eyedropper) the area around the blue square is only transparent on the left image.

Here is the same image with the color values:

[image: Same image with color values]

I know it's barely visible but I'd like to know what causes this.
Plus with some images and backgrounds, the contrast is more noticeable.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Here's my VS solution for those who want to try it at home: http://www.mediafire.com/?gt704e62d53z7ae

Comment: I can confirm that I also see this behavior. I tested with both 32-bit and 8-bit PNG images, with no difference in output. Smells like a rendering defect.

Comment: That's also my guess. Did you come up with a workaround?

Comment: No, I did not find any workaround.

Comment: My guess is that Silverlight is doing a [premultiplied alpha blending](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/11/06/premultiplied-alpha.aspx), just like XNA. But it's just a guess.

Comment: What did you expect to happen when opacity is set to 10%? To me, the #514846 seems to be the correct color.

Comment: When some pixels are transparent, I expect them to remain transparent, whatever the opacity. Transparent is transparent. There are no different "shades" of transparency.

Comment: Dragos Calin, thanks for the link. This doesn't help me but at least, I think I understand the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not anti-aliasing, and most likely not a [Premultiplied Alpha Blending](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/11/06/premultiplied-alpha.aspx) as its purpose is to do what you're doing.

It seems most like a rendering issue.

Have you tried this in several browsers? On a different machine with different GPU? On the same machine with updated drivers?

Comment: Same effect with Chrome 17, Firefox 10 and IE 9... And I tried it in-browser and out-of-browser on 4 different computers, but they were all running Windows 7... But I didn't check the GPU or whether the drivers were up to date. If you want to try, here's the source: http://www.mediafire.com/?gt704e62d53z7ae

Comment: Unfortunately my employer's websense policy is nazi, so I can't grab the source. The fact that it happens across all browsers makes me continue to think Windows 7 GPU Driver quirk.

Comment: That's too bad I have no other Windows version at hand... Anyway, I gladly award you the bounty. ;o)

Answer (score 0):

It could be anti-aliasing causing a blend between the transparent 'frame' and the semi-transparent 'blue square' causing the strange intermediate color ghosting you are seeing.

Comment: I think Dragos' answer about premultiplied alpha blending is the right one. But thanks anyway.